# How to install Eclipse IDE for JavaScript platform on Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, eclipse, ubuntu

I installed Eclipse by `sudo apt-get install eclipse` but seems it does not support JavaSript files editing. the link http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-javascript-web-developers/heliosr provides binaries for JavaScript Eclispe platform but I don't know how to install it on my Ubuntu 12.04. I am a beginner of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Can you install it via the eclipse marketplace client?

I've only skimmed this video but it looks like it atleast has the basics right:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfp5FOJtack

Comment: I have no access to youtube, so I followed you instruction searched for Eclipse Marketplace Client and referred to this link http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro. however, I checked the Help menu from Eclipse there is no such Market place menu. the version of my Eclipse is 3.7.2 and apt-get checks it is the latest.